# how should the dataset be provided to nanocubes?

Tags: database, visualization, data-cube

If anyone could help me with how the dataset should be fed into nanocubes, it would be wonderful.

Github link
https://github.com/laurolins/nanocube

Paper
http://www.research.att.com/techdocs/TD_101151.pdf

Example dataset view
http://www.nanocubes.net/view.html#brightkite